# Inserting an element at a given position in an array, the last few elements are not showing in the array

Tags: c

I was trying to insert an item in the given array but in the ,output the last element is not taken by the code given below. Can anyone please explain me why is it so??  Actually I don't know how to give reference but I have tried something. About the reference part, I have given reference to n but when the function is called it gives Runtime Error. Can anyone help me in this part?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int insertAtGP(int *a, int *n, int item, int k)
{
    int j;
    j = *n - 1;
    while(j >= k) 
    {
        a[j+1] = a[j];
        j--;
    }
    a[k] = item;
    (*n)++;
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    int arr[] = {45, 50, 25, 61, 34};
    insertAtGP(arr, 5, 30, 3);
    for(i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d\n ",*(arr+ i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your array "arr" only has five elements, and you do things with the sixth. Anything can happen, and usually nothing good.

Comment: Your `for` loop iterates over 5 elements, so even if we ignore the undefined behaviour caused by accessing the 6th element of a 5-large array, you simply can't expect more than 5 elements in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int arr[6] = {45, 50, 25, 61, 34};//Size after insertion is necessary. 5 < array size
int size = 5;//Actual data size of the original
insertAtGP(arr, &size, 30, 3);//2nd argument requires a pointer to int,
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)//use the updated value. = Does not include
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behavior.

You can't validly index past the end of an array, and your array only has room for the number of elements present in the initializer, i.e. 5.